# How do I create a field that accepts only unique values?

Tags: 7, entities

I am using the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module because I have some complicated relation between the fields, and I have tried to integrate it with the [Unique field](http://drupal.org/project/unique_field) module, without success, because [Unique field](http://drupal.org/project/unique_field) module is not supported by the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module.

Is there a simpler method to check if the value is unique, and the to display validation error, if the value is not unique?

Unfortunately, Drupal 7 has not this feature by default, so there must be a method to do this.

Comment: I wasn't aware field collection had limitations on what types could be attached.  Can you describe what happened when you tried to attach a unique_field to a collection?  Also, what is your criteria for uniqueness in this case?  A unique entity-id for the collection?  A unique combination of values (analogous to a compound key in a database)?  Or a unique value in one of the collections' fields?

Comment: The criteria for uniqueness is the value in the filed. Actually is a string which act as a serial number.

Comment: I found a way to verify if the value of a field is unique, but it's usable only if the field contains a reference to an entity. I don't think you are interested to such limited case.

Comment: If the two modules are incompatible, that's a bug. There has been nothing filed in the Field Collection queue, have you filed an issue with Unique Field?

Comment: I would post this as an answer, but I am not terribly familiar with this aspect of the D7 API yet.  Can a query and uniqueness check just be done in a hook_node_validate()?

Comment: @kiamlaluno, please tell me your solution because I also a filed called Product, which has type Node reference (form Reference module) in my field collection entity ...however I don't understand how can this field affect the uniqueness of my other field, the Serial No?

Comment: The solution I have in mind should be implemented by the module that handles the field, but it would not work as the module doesn't have any information about the database table used to contain all the field values.

Comment: @tim.plunkett, please be free to open a issue concerning this problem.

Comment: @Ek Kosmos, I'm the Field Collection co-maintainer, feel free to file an issue.

Comment: @tim just for the sake of my curiosity, what would be the best way to retrieve values from fields inside field collection, because I kind of felt dirty with my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally here is how I did adapting and tacking suggestions form @tostinni, @stefgosselin, @uwe999 answers and others:

```
/**
 * implementation of hook_form_alter().
 */
function CUSTOM_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    switch ($form_id) {
        case 'MY_FORM_ID':
            // add custom validation callback
            $form['#validate'][] = 'CUSTOM_MODULE_MY_FORM_ID_validate';
            break;
            ...
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

then all the functionality I implemented in:

```
/**
 * implementation of hook_form_FORM_ID_alter
 */
function CUSTOM_MODULE_MY_FORM_ID_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {

    //retrieve the value for your field
    $value = $form_state['values']['field_MY_FIELD']['und'][0]['value'];

    //Execute a count query to see if there's other similar values.
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery;
    $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'field_collection_item')
            ->fieldCondition('field_MY_FIELD', 'value', $value)
            ->count();
    $count = $query->execute();
    if ($count > 0) {
        form_set_error('field_MY_FIELD', 'Unique field value is already used.');
    }
}
```

I have tried to work with `entity_metadata_wrapper` but unfortunately I have not succeed.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 8):

You need to implement this in a custom module, here is a sample code to achieve this:

```php
function custom_node_validate($node, $form) {
  if ($node->type == 'page') {
    //retrieve the value for your field using Entity API
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
    $value = $wrapper->field_collection->field_unique->value();

    //Execute a count query to see if there's other similar values.
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery;
    $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'field_collection_item')
      ->fieldCondition('field_unique', 'value', $value)
      ->count();
    $count = $query->execute();
    if ($count > 1) {
      form_set_error('field_unique', 'Unique field value is already used.');
    }
  }
}
```

A few disclaimers:

- I am really stocked by the complexity of <strike>Field</strike> Field Collection API and it was pretty complicated to find good information about how to retrieve values and make queries.
- I really enjoy doing SQL queries (see [How to change the legnth of field settings](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/how-to-change-the-length-of-field-settings/10005#10005)) but I tried to only use the API instead of doing a simple query on the table `field_data_field_unique`. However it may not yet be perfect so please feel free to chime in.
- The [form_set_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_error) isn't highliting the field, I was unable to find the correct name.

Here are the documentation I used:

- [hook_node_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7)
- [Get value of a field collection field](http://drupal.org/node/1166238#comment-4580004) (answer from fago), the [Entity API](http://drupal.org/project/entity) module and [entity_metadata_wrapper()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--entity--entity.module/function/entity_metadata_wrapper/7).
- [Checking out EntityFieldQuery](http://www.commerceguys.com/resources/articles/183) (by Ryan Szrama) and the [API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7).

**Edit:** Following chx advice, to pass directly `field_name` to `fieldCondition()`.

Comment: It boggles my mind why on earth would you need entity API for this. Why are you not doing simple `$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_unique'); $value = $items[0];` ? Next up, there is no need to run `field_info_field()` you can happily pass a field_name to `fieldCondition`. Finally, I think the name of the field would be `field_unique[LANGUAGE_NONE]`

Comment: The problem here is Field Collection, field_unique is attached to field_collection so field_get_items can't retrieve it directly. I feel the same, this look way over engineered but I couldn't find a better API. Regarding the `field_unique[LANGUAGE_NONE]` it doesn't work as field collection gets in the middle. Thanks for your tips :)

Answer (score 4):

I haven't programmed a module yet but it sounds like it might be easier to write a hook on form_alter and then query against your existing "serial number" field to make sure it's unique.

Comment: Yes, this could be a good idea I think.

Answer (score 1):

Basically Ek Kosmos has the basic idea. The easiest would be to create a small *custom* module, this has the advantage of isolating the feature you want to build, and remember the #1 rule, you really never want to hack anything in core, unless you really cannot avoid it.

Once you have your .info file setup in a folder and .module file ready to go as indicated in the [many how-to's on the subject](http://drupal.org/node/1074360), you leverage the power of hook_form_alter by writing a function named *your-module-name* _form_alter in your module file and you know that function will be called.

You would probably need a switch statement dependent in the form)alter to perform specific actions depending on  the *form id*,

You would probably  need to try adding an attribute (#validate) that adds a function call on the form array, being a function name of your own custom  validation function.

Something like:

```
   // #validate adds callback to custom validator.
   $validators = $form['#validate'][]; // Save existing validation calls. 
   //  Not clear in docs, but this is important!

  // In your case, you may want to add a method callback with this attribute.                                   
  $form['#validate'][] = $validators . ' _custom_validate';
```

Of course, in your validation function you could log errors, redirect, assign error messages or notifications.

Do read the [form api and download the form examples](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/form%20api).

If you need help and examples galore, download contrib modules and see how others tackeled the beast, or post questions here as you go along.

Happy conding, good-luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [field validation](http://drupal.org/project/field_validation) module, use unique validator.
Add a validation rule, choose unique scope, global, entity,bundle.