# Validate based on existing CCK field value?

Tags: entities, 6

I have a content type with an address field in it. My client has requested that when saving, the site should check whether another node (of the same content type) already has that address.

I.e., I want the content type to validate if and only if the address being given hasn't been used.

How do I do this? Using Drupal 6, by the way.

Comment: Potential dup of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10089/how-do-i-create-a-field-that-accepts-only-unique-values but for D6 instead of D7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use hook_nodeapi for this!

In this example I'm assuming the node type is *blah*

In a custom module just write something along the lines of:

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  if ($op == 'validate' && $node->type == 'blah') {
    $sql = db_query("SELECT bl.field_address 
           FROM {content_type_blah} bl
           WHERE bl.field_address = '%s'", $node->field_address)

    if ($sql != '') {
        form_set_error($node->field_address, t('This address is already being used'));
    }
  }
}
```

That way, before a node is saved (during the validation) it runs an SQL query to see if the address field is duplicated anywhere else on any other node with the type *blah*.  If it is, then it throws an error on the form field!  You will need to tweak the query dependant on your table names etc.

I'm only writing that code from the top of my head, and I've not tested it (sorry) but it should definately be a starting point!  I may have the $node->field_address part wrong!

If all else fails, put a `die(print_r($node));` after the `if ($op == 'validate'...` line and you can get the right part from that!

Hope this helps :)

References:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/5
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_error/6

Comment: Rather than hardcoding the table name, you should use CCK's API to get it. You can use [`content_fields($field_name, $content_type_name)`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--cck--content.module/function/content_fields/6) to get the field definition, and then pass that to [`content_database_info()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--cck--content.module/function/content_database_info/6) to get both the table and column name reliably.

Comment: Nice, hadn't thought of that!  If it works then it's definately more portable/userful :)