# Gmap/location design question

Tags: 6, location, google-maps

Which modules and function should I use to store address of house and also display Google Map of it? I also want to use postal code, province, city each in views etc independently.

I understand I should use GMAP + location.

But not sure if I need to use Location CCK or Node Locations.

What is the best way to accept address and also show Google map in the node?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the relative merits of Node locations vs Location CCK for this scenario, but the CCK option's worked for me. **Edit:** With GMap enabled, you can select a Google Map as the field's formatter by going to *Content management* -> *Content types* -> *Edit [content type]* -> *Display fields*. If GMap's enabled, you should see an option *Map only*. CCK will handle storing the data. See [my comment on this Q](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/12087/633) for how to get the table details. **Edit2:** Actually, if memory serves, Location doesn't store the CCK data as you might first expect. location.module stores locations in its own table, and the CCK field just stores an ID into that table.

Comment: How'd the location fields be stored? I mean City,Province,Postal code etc .. will they be stored in separate fields in node table?

Comment: Where is the place to select Google Map as field's formatter? All I see is "Location Field" in formatter. I've enabled Location CCK, Gmap, Gmap location modules. Are you using Gmap macro expander in Input Formats?

Comment: @AgA have updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with Location CCK. Node Location is a holdover from before CCK (and now Fields in Drupal 7) was a mature system, I can't see any reason to use that on a new application. Use Location CCK, and GMAP to show multiple nodes on a single map with views.