# Simple cycle that pick next free id

Tags: 7

What I'm trying to do is function working like this:

```
function my_function($id){
   while($id){
      if($id = not free){
          $id=$id+'1';
      } else {
          return $id;
      }
   }
}
```

I'm new to php and drupal generally and can't figure out how to handle this cycle.
For instance, 'if statement' should test if the id is already in database. If it is then +1 to id if not return this free id.

I'm using this to check whether the id is free or not:

```
$check_unique_station_id = 'SELECT field_station_id_value FROM {field_data_field_station_id} WHERE field_station_id_value = :input_id LIMIT 1';   
if (db_query($check_unique_station_id, array(':input_id'=>$input_id))->fetchField()){

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

//EDIT

I guess I didn't explain it well. I have custom module and few custom fields. One of them is 'station_id' which is field for storing number (type) of station. Let's say it is a name of the station expressed in number.
Here is an example of values I have in database in field_station_id:

1. 22
2. 45
3. 89

Now what I want to do: when user input=22 then check if 22 already exists and if so check if exist 22+1. When input=45 then return 46 etc.
Now I see that I explained it really bad. Hope that now you know what I mean.

// EDIT 2
// MY SOLUTION

I came up with this piece of code. However I was just wondering if there is some query function to do it (propably faster). As mentioned by Felix downthere (pick as the right answer) it seems that the only query function founds the maximum number in db and return it. Which is not what I want.

Here is my code:

```
function free_value($occupied_value){

// loads all used values from db
$query_all_occupied_values = 'SELECT field_station_value FROM {field_data_field_station_value} WHERE field_station_value >= :occupied_value ORDER BY field_station_value';
$all_occupied_values = db_query($query_all_occupied_values, array(':occupied_value'=>$occupied_value))->fetchAll();

// count number of rows of used station_values
$number_of_values = count($all_occupied_values)-1;

// finds first closest value which is not occupied in db
for($i=0; $i<=$number_of_values; $i++) {
    if($occupied_value == $all_occupied_values[$i]->field_station_value) {
        $occupied_value = $occupied_value+1;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

$free_value = $occupied_value;

return $free_value;
```

}

Comment: Hello and welcome. Would you mind telling us what you are trying to accomplish? Drupal uses next free ID by default in all typical situations already.

Comment: Hi. I have a custom module that adds my custom content with some fields. One of the field is 'station_id' which I want to test whether is already use or not. Is it enough? I can describe it more if neccesary.

Comment: But if you are using [Field API](https://drupal.org/community-initiatives/drupal-core/fields) to manage your fields, it will never be needed. And if you are not, you can make ID an auto-increment field in database and again, searching for next free value will never be needed. So I still don't know what and why you are doing.

Comment: I'm little confused now. Let's have an example: User wants to add 'station_id' number 33. But when 33 is already used before I want to check which next number is free and get it to the user. How can I manage it with Field API?

Comment: I could use somthing like [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10089/how-do-i-create-a-field-that-accepts-only-unique-values) but still I want to offer to user next free id which can be used.

Comment: Why does the user need to be aware of the ID at all? It is just an arbitrary number used as a unique identifier. If the ID has a specific meaning to the user other than this maybe it would be better to add field for it, rather than using the key field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will select the next free ID:

```
$next_free_id = db_query("SELECT MAX(field_name) + 1 FROM table_name")->fetchField();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see edited question. I can't try it now but I suppose that your querry returns maxed value. In example I wrote in edited question it would return 89+1. (if I'm not wrong)