# Node Revision Table Deletion

Tags: nodes

I have a drupal site. The node revision is about 3.1gb in size. My hosting company will not allow me to login to the drupal site. I only have access to my phpadmin. If I empty the node revision table. Can I force a new revision node?

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/16478/1899

Comment: THis is a very bad idea and will probably leave your database in a inconsistent state. Get a better web host.