# Copy values from one field to another

Tags: entities, nodes

I've run into a problem where i set the maximum length of a field to short. There are 500+ nodes using this field so delete and re-write everything would be very time consuming. Is there an easy way to copy the values to another/new field with longer maximum lenght?

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you asking how to do this rather than asking how to increase the maximum length of the existing field?

Comment: [This is a Duplicate of this link](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/how-to-change-the-length-of-field-settings) where you'll find your answer ;) enjoy

Comment: Clive: Because I thought that copying the existing field would be safer than to start messing with the database.

Comment: Kojo: I can't post comments to any posts but it doesn't work for me so I need to post a new thread.