# Max length of text field

Tags: nodes, 7

[image]

How can I increase the max lenght of Tab-Title ?

Answer (score 0):

With module: [Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/title) you can convert title to field and then you can change the field length

For title-tab goto: `admin/structure/types/manage` choose your content type and then `manage fields` `edit` your field

Comment: oh sorry, I was thinking you want to change title, not title-tab

Answer (score 0):

[Maxlength](https://www.drupal.org/project/maxlength)

> Maxlength allows you to set maximum length of any field on any form
>   making use of the form API. This includes fields created using the UI.
>   (Example: any text field on a node) In D6 Maxlength allows you to set
>   maximum lengths to the body, title and CCK textfields of any content
>   type (node).

**By custom**

explain by [tostinni](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/how-to-change-the-length-of-field-settings)

Comment: How does that increase the max length of the field in the database though?

Comment: check this link explain in it http://www.automation-excellence.com/blog/extending-drupal-7-text-field-character-limit

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for my question.
I have create a custom_field_length.module.
In custom_field_length module I have add this code.

```
function custom_field_length_change_text_field_max_length($field_name, $new_length) {
 $field_table = 'field_data_' . $field_name;
 $field_revision_table = 'field_revision_' . $field_name;
 $field_column = $field_name . '_value'; 

 // Alter value field length in fields table
db_query("ALTER TABLE `{$field_table}` CHANGE `{$field_column}` `{$field_column}` VARCHAR( {$new_length} )");

// Alter value field length in fields revision table
db_query("ALTER TABLE `{$field_revision_table}` CHANGE `{$field_column}` `{$field_column}` VARCHAR( {$new_length} )");

// Update field config with new max length
$result = db_query("SELECT CAST(`data` AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8) FROM `field_config` WHERE field_name = '{$field_name}'");
$config = $result->fetchField();
$config_array = unserialize($config);
$config_array['settings']['max_length'] = $new_length;
$config = serialize($config_array);
db_update('field_config')
    ->fields(array('data' => $config))
    ->condition('field_name', $field_name)
    ->execute();
}

function custom_field_length_update_8002() {
  custom_field_length_change_text_field_max_length('field_tab_title', 255);
}
```

After enable module I will run update.php after that my field size is increase to 255.