# Addressfield change max size of column

Tags: 7, entities, database

I'm working with the addressfield module. I need to change the thoroughfare column to have a max length of 960 (or make it a text instead of varchar) instead of the default 255.

However I'm not sure how I should do it.

I've created an empty module with a hook_schema_alter()

```
function hook_schema_alter(&$schema) {
  $schema['addressfield']['thoroughfare'] = array(
    'description' => 'The thoroughfare of this address. (i.e. Street address)',
    'type' => 'text',
    'default' => '',
    'not null' => FALSE,
  );
  return $schema;
}
```

However I suspect that the part "$schema['addressfield']['thoroughfare']" is not correct. Nothing is changed when I install the module with this hook.

How to change it? In the original addressfield it returns only columns in the schema hook, it's not really linked to a schema itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That** approach won't affect the column type or size as I get you need to make it store more chars.

**You** could do **hook_update_N()** that execute a sql query to change the field type and size.

**Then** yo have to change field settings [**see**](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/how-to-change-the-length-of-field-settings)